# Sync Blackberry, iPhone and Outlook contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, iphone, sync, gmail, blackberry

Here is what I have:

I have a personal laptop that syncs my contacts from the address book to my @gmail.com account. This then syncs to my personal iPhone via the pseudo-Exchange account that Gmail can masquerade as. All good.

Now I have a work laptop, running Outlook via Exchange and a BES-connected Blackberry. This has a copy of my personal contacts from when I first started however, as expected, is now out of sync with my iPhone. The problem I have got is I can't just blow away the contacts on my Blackberry as I have company ones then (which are syncing to my outlook).

I am happy in all of this for my work contacts to sync to my personal phone and vice versa but I can't seem to find a way that works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could sync your work laptop contacts with your gmail account and have gmail manage all your contacts. In gmail contacts you can use categories to separate personal and professional contacts.

Doing it this way, you would need to run the Google Apps Sync client on both your computers regularly.

I, on the other hand, cope with the same problem in a slightly different way. I sync mi personal iPhone with my professional Exchange server, and keep all my contacts, both professional and personal, there. That way I have both my iPhone and my BB in sync with the contacts. I separate my contacts in Outlook using two different folders, one for professional contacts and another for personal ones.

In any case, there is no definite way to solve this kind of problem. I hope I was helpful.